# How to call external API in IBM Watson Conversation

Tags: node.js, ibm-watson

I am trying to call the node service developed in actions in `ibm watson` conversation.
I am inputting two values say username and father name:

[image].

Right now there is just a link to call the external API (link for user details). I want to get the user details directly in chatbot as response once the username and fathername are entered.

I developed a node service for this. But I am not able to figure out how to connect chatbot dialog to node service.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Did you go through the dialog actions documentation? - https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/dialog-actions.html#dialog-actions

Answer (score 0):

You can either make programmatic calls from the dialog node using IBM Cloud Functions.

https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/dialog-actions.html#dialog-actions

or you need to carry out an action, based on the detected intents.

https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/develop-app.html#implementing-app-actions

Comment: Have you tried with this document. I am having an action created for getting userdetails based on some input. The response should be returned in the dialog node of chatbot. Can you tell how to connect action to my chatbot?